# how can i print something in a for loop only once

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm making a hangman game and I'm a beginner, I can't figure out how to make the for loop print only once:

```py
for char in word:
    if char in guesses:
        print (char)
        print("correct!")
    else:
        print("_")
```

So is wanna print "correct" only once but right now it's printing it every time a correct letter is inserted

Comment: Is the "correct" supposed to signal that the solution has been found or just that the last guess was in the word?

Comment: @schwobaseggl its supposed to mean that the last guess was correct

Comment: The last guess is not in your code, or is guesses a list that contains all guesses in order?

Answer (score 0):

You might give more info about your code and the input. However, perhaps this can help:

```
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5]

for i in (x):
    if i ==1:
        found=True
        print ("correct!")
        break
    else:
        print ("_")
```

"break" can stop the loop

Answer (score -1):

You can use a boolean to avoid printing something more than once in a loop:

```
printed = False
for char in word:
    if char in guesses:
        print (char)
        if not printed:
            print("correct!")
            printed = True
    else:
        print("_")
```

Answer (score -1):

This will print `"correct"` if the last guess was in the word and then output the typical hangman string.

```
if guesses[-1] in word:
    print("correct!")
print(''.join(c if c in guesses else '_' for c in word))
```